# How do I change all values in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

At the moment I have a column that says:

```
Year
2000 [YR 2000]
2001 [YR 2001]
```

I'd like to drop the extra [YR 2000] part of it. Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Actually his question doesnt need removing substrings, but just tokens. Similar, but computationally different.

Comment: `df["Year"]=df["Year"].str.replace(r"\s*\[[^\]]*\]", "", regex=True)` will do

Answer (score 0):

Use this -

```
df['Year'] = df['Year'].apply(lambda x:x.split()[0])
```